# Contar cuantos archivos tiene una directorio con JAVA

Tags: java

Quiero saber si se puede obtener el numero de archivos de una carpeta con java, ya que he visto en la web que lo realizan agregando a un `list` cada archivo.

Pero estoy trabajando con carpetas arriba de **100.000 archivos** y es muy **lento** el proceso, habrá alguna forma de solo traer el numero sin realizar un conteo con lista?

Comment: Es en inglés, pero aqui tiene una respuesta: https://www.javabrahman.com/corejava/how-to-count-number-of-files-in-a-directory-in-java-file-list-vs-nios-directorystream/

Comment: Recuerda que se sugiere agregar lo que has tratado o investigado a tu pregunta, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0

Sólo hay ficheros o ficheros y carpetas juntos?. Si sólo hay ficheros se solucionaría con un simple length()

```
File carpeta = new File("Ruta"); 
File[] lista = carpeta.listFiles();
System.out.println("\n Hay " +  lista.length + " elementos");
```

Si están mezclados archivos y carpetas creo que es inevitable que hagas un for con un if, para poder separar los que son realmente archivos, de aquellos que son carpetas, algo así...

```
File carpeta = new File("E:\\Documentación"); 
File[] lista = carpeta.listFiles();    
int cuenta=0;

  for (int i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) 
      if (lista[i].isFile())
           cuenta++;
  System.out.println("\n Hay " +  cuenta + " archivos");
```

O sea, no creo que puedes contar los ficheros en bloque si están mezclados con carpetas.